# Pagination of QGraphicsTextItem: Confining text to a specific rectangular area

Tags: python, c++, qt, pagination, qgraphicstextitem

I am trying to use Qt for creating a WYSIWYG word processor, focusing mainly on the layout of pages and pagination of a document.

The first thing I'm trying to focus on is a printing preview feature and I thought I would use a QGraphicsScene/View along with a QGraphicsTextItem.

The current problem is that I am unable to contain the text within the confines of the QGraphicsTextItem. The text keeps going until it hits the bottom of the QGraphicsScene/View.[image: Preview]

I am wondering if using QGraphics is the correct way to go about it and if so, what should I do to get pagination for my text document?

Code (PyQt, but I should be able to understand C++ even though Python is preferred) for producing the result showed in the attached picture:

```
import sys

from PyQt4.QtGui import \
QApplication, \
QDialog, \
QGraphicsScene, \
QGraphicsView, \
QVBoxLayout, \
QPainter

from PyQt4.QtCore import \
QRectF, \
Qt


class GraphicsView(QGraphicsView):
    def __init__(self, fname='', parent=None):
        super(GraphicsView, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setDragMode(QGraphicsView.RubberBandDrag)
        self.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing)
        self.setRenderHint(QPainter.TextAntialiasing)

    def wheelEvent(self, event):
        factor = 1.41 ** (-event.delta() / 240.0)
        self.scale(factor, factor)


class Editor(QDialog):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Editor, self).__init__(parent)

        pageSize = (842, 198)
        f = open('alotbsol.txt')
        txt = f.read()

        view = GraphicsView()
        scene = QGraphicsScene(self)
        scene.setSceneRect(0, 0, pageSize[0], pageSize[1])
        rect = QRectF(0, 0, pageSize[0], pageSize[1])
        scene.addRect(rect, Qt.black)
        textbox = scene.addText(txt)
        textbox.setTextWidth(pageSize[0])
        view.setScene(scene)

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(view, 1)
        self.setLayout(layout)

        self.resize(scene.width() + 50, scene.height() * 2)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    widget = Editor()
    widget.show()
    app.exec_()*emphasized text*
```

Answer (score 1):

Qt supports rich text processing by [The Scribe framework](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/richtext.html). It is based on the  `QTextDocument` which is a container for structured rich text documents. The Scribe framework consists of classes for reading and manipulating rich text documents. You can find more about the structured representation of a text document [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/richtext-structure.html).

For paginating your document when printing you can convert your text to HTML and render it using `QTextDocument`, Qt's rich text engine. Although you can perform the drawing and the page breaking by hand, but converting a document to HTML and using `QTextDocument` to print it is by far the most convenient alternative for printing reports and other complex documents :

```
void Dialog::Print(QString myText)
{

    QPrinter printer;

    QString html = QString("<P>%1</P>").arg(myText);

    QPrintDialog printDialog(&printer, this);
    if (printDialog.exec()) {
        textDocument.setHtml(html);

        QPrintPreviewDialog preview(&printer, this);
        preview.setWindowFlags ( Qt::Window );
        connect(&preview, SIGNAL(paintRequested(QPrinter *)), SLOT(printPreview(QPrinter *)));
        preview.exec();
    }

}

void Dialog::printPreview(QPrinter * printer)
{
    textDocument.print(printer);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have been exploring QTextDocument as well, but I have not been able to find a good way to do pagination for QTextDocument instances. Could you please state the basic idea behind paginating a QTextDocument instance?

Comment: @jollyroger The answer is updated to show how to paginate using a `QTextDocument`.

Comment: I tried to copy your example, but the only thing that happened was that I made a physical paper printout of the text. This is not at all what I was looking for. I need to have the virtual pages displayed on screen and the printDialog didn't even have this in place.

Comment: @jollyroger You are right, The answer is updated. It uses `QPrintPreviewDialog` to show the preview of the print.

Comment: Thank you for the update. You are showing me many things about Qt I find interesting and valuable to know about. I apologize if my initial question was unclear, but what I want to learn is how to implement something like the QPrintPreviewDialog myself. I'll try to have a look in the source code, but I would really appreciate someone telling me the basic idea of how to implement a print preview.